# What is the expected load time for a website or email on a smart phone?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, time, loading

I saw couple of statistics showing page abandonment as loading time increases, but haven't found any resource which would specifically deal with "mobile" users only.

Obviously this question can be tricky since the download speed will depend a lot on the actual connection (2G, 3G, 4G) of the visitor, but still it would be exciting to know their behaviors.

Do you know about any study in this field?

Answer (score -1):

On his article on [website response times](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/website-response-times/) Jakob Nielsen points out that load times are not that big an issue anymore, response times are.

> Today, most people have broadband, so you might think that download times are no longer a usability concern. And yes, actual image download is rarely an issue for today's wireline users (though images can still cause delays on mobile devices).
>
> Still, response times are as relevant as ever. That's because responsiveness is a basic user interface design rule that's dictated by human needs, not by individual technologies. In a client usability study we just completed, for example, users complained that "it's being a little slow."

And then goes on to mention the classic 0.1s, 1s, 10s rules from [Response Times: The 3 Important Limits](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/).

But at the of the article is this little tidbit, emphasis added:

> Response times are a matter of user experience: How much time does it take before the computer is ready to serve the user? **The reasons behind delays don't matter to users.** All they know is that they're getting poor service, which is annoying.

edit: As stated in both quotes, how long the load time is even in 2G, doesn't matter. What matters is how fast the application responses to user's interaction. Response time and load time are **not** the same thing. It doesn't matter whether the connection is wired or not, 2G or fiber optics.

Comment: On a 3G - H connection (1.5Mbit/s) it can take like 5.3s + response time to download 1 MB. So I have to argue with the "load times are not a big issue" statement. 

Based on the actual download speeds published here: http://kenstechtips.com/index.php/download-speeds-2g-3g-and-4g-actual-meaning

Comment: The question is about mobile phones and this answer states load times aren't important, however, the first quote is about wired users, not mobile so it doesn't apply here.